# Magento: Programmatically apply catalog price rule to order

Tags: php, magento

I have created a catalog price rule and it is working fine when placing orders from front end. But, when I programmatically create orders through custom code, this rules were found not working eventhough I am assigning this particular order to a customer who is belongs to the provided customer group. Can anybody help on this ? Please see related code below:

```
....
//Setting customer group ID

     $this->_quote->setCustomerGroupId(9); 
    ...
```

............

```
//$currentProduct - product Object
//$curQuantity - Product quantity
$this->_quote->addProduct($currentProduct,new Varien_Object(array('qty'=> $curQuantity)));
```

.............

Thanks!
Iqbal.

Comment: My question in another words: "How can I apply catalog rules to a Quote object programatically ?". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To apply the catalog price rule to the quote object programatically, use this

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')
    ->getQuote()
    ->setCouponCode(strlen($couponCode) ? $couponCode : '')
    ->collectTotals()
    ->save();
```

Comment: Thank You for response! But, I have already done this; but still not working. code: $this->_quote->setCouponCode('')->save();  - I have no coupon code set for this rule.